# Preventing context XML from being override in Tomcat 6

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I am using JNDI to read database configuration from my application's context.xml.  The way I currently have this setup is to have [appname].xml in conf/Catalina/localhost.  However, when I redeploy the app, this file gets overridden with an empty context file, and I have to copy the custom one back to the conf/Catalina/localhost directory.  I have different database settings, etc. for my test and production servers, and so don't want to put the context file in META-INF in the WAR file, but would like to just keep it in the conf/Catalina/localhost directory.  Is this possible?

Is there somewhere better to put the database configuration?

I'd also like to avoid putting the configuration in the server.xml file, although I know this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: what tool are you using to assemble your war (Ant, Maven, ...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say look into using maven profiles (one for prod, one for test), and having different resource definitions for each profile. You can keep your common files in src/main/resources and then have a folder for each profile type to keep specific config files in:

- src/test/resources
- src/prod/resources

Then you can amend your pom to define each profile and its associated resources:

```
<project>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
          </resource>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/prod/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
          </resource>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

finally you can build the war using the -Pprod or -Ptest profile argument to mvn

```
mvn -Pprod package
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that undeploy removed the webapp specific context.xml file that was installed in Catalina/localhost/.xml

If you don't want to have the file removed, you'll have to just redeploy it, not undeploy/deploy